# Criteria for choosing which common data formats to support for tabular data in a simple ML library

Tags: libraries, data

**What criteria does one consider when choosing which data formats a library for doing some machine learning task should support for reading/writing tabular (i.e. non-[hierarchical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model)) data?** I found [a similar question on what language to write a general-purpose ML library in](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/126710/105784), but not one for data formats. I have a number of requirements for the library in mind, but I do not know how to evaluate a potential data format in regards to these requirements and how to choose which one(s) best fit my use.

### Requirements

- The library is not designed to be used with any other specific program/library in mind, i.e. I don't already "know" beforehand that it will be used by e.g. [gnuplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot)
- The library is for exploratory research and so it's not being made with a specific "real-life" application in mind
- The library is intended to be a simple "input-output" data-processing library (cf. the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy))
- At the moment, I will be the primary user of the library but I will more than likely be sharing the data with other people in the future (although I'm not yet sure whom exactly) and I intend to make the library freely available online in some form, so it's hard to say exactly who will be using my data format(s)
- The amount of data handled is quite large but not astronomical
- Human readability would be a huge advantage so that people can "eyeball" the data for insight/error checking
- Performance is not a huge issue since this is not for real-time processing

Comment: Are you asking for a data format that meets these requirements? (which seems off-topic for the same reasons as tool/library recommendations) Or are you asking whether this list of requirements is the correct one for all machine language tasks which require a data format? (which seems both too broad and opinion-based)